# C#: Deleting Windows Temporary Internet Files does not delete user visible files

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, filesystems

**EDIT (01/24/2015) NOTE:** While trying to figure out why this wasn't working, prior to asking questions here, I learned that the Temporary Internet Files directory is actually a virtual directory managed by windows. If you use a program like 7zip to browse your Temporary Internet Files directory, you will see the actual file system.

My goal is to delete Windows Temporary Internet Files. I have used 7zip to view the directories structure of

```
C:\User\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

And saw that there were 3 directories: Content.IE5, Low, and Virtualized.

By looking into these directories, I assume I should only be deleting the contents of Content.IE5 and Low. I then used

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
string path1 = path + "\\Content.IE5\\";
string path2 = path + "\\Low\\";
```

With a foreach to delete all files and sub-directories of those two directories.

From looking in 7zip I was able to verify that the directories and files were deleted, but when I go to

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

Nothing has been deleted. How do I delete the files that I can view from within Windows Explorer?

**EDIT(01/23/2015):** Here is my code. If anyone can help, it would be really appreciated as I don't know what else to do since it is deleting the files and folders that I can see with 7zip but it is not deleting what is seen in the virtual directory.

```
        Dictionary<string,DirectoryInfo> directories = new Dictionary<string,DirectoryInfo>() {
        {"Temporary Internet Files", new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache))}
    };
        DirectoryInfo dInfoTempIntFilesCont = new DirectoryInfo(directories["Temporary Internet Files"] + "\\Content.IE5\\");
        DirectoryInfo dInfoTempIntFilesLow = new DirectoryInfo(directories["Temporary Internet Files"] + "\\Low\\");

        FileInfo[] fInfoTempIntFiles = directories["Temporary Internet Files"].GetFiles();

        DirectoryInfo[] fInfoTempIntFilesCont = dInfoTempIntFilesCont.GetDirectories();
        DirectoryInfo[] fInfoTempIntFilesLow = dInfoTempIntFilesLow.GetDirectories();

        try
        {
            foreach (var file in fInfoTempIntFiles)
            {
                try
                {
                    file.Delete();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }

            foreach (var subDirectory in fInfoTempIntFilesCont)
            {
                try
                {
                    subDirectory.Delete(true);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }

            foreach (var subDirectory in fInfoTempIntFilesLow)
            {
                try
                {
                    subDirectory.Delete(true);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
```

**EDIT (01/24/2015):** Here is the proof that the Environment path is correct as well as the result of GetFiles on it.

[image: Temporary Internet Files path and result of GetFiles()]

Answer (score 0):

Remove your empty catch blocks and the system will tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I think you may have missed the part where I can see it deleting the virtual files. It's working. It must simply not be hitting the location of the files that you can see when you go to Temporary Internet Files through Windows Explorer.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean... what do you mean by 'virtual' files and why are you using 7zip as a file browser? Did you verify that Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache); is returning C:\User\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files?

Comment: While trying to figure out why this wasn't working, prior to asking questions here, I learned that the Temporary Internet Files directory is actually a virtual directory managed by windows. If you use a program like 7zip to browse your Temporary Internet Files directory, you will see the actual file system. I thank you in trying to help.

Comment: I added an edit to my question that demonstrates the path and result of GetFiles. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access shell virtual folders, you'll use the shell scripting objects.  To get started, add a reference to

```
using System;
using Shell32;

namespace SO28073584
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sh = (IShellDispatch4)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
            var tempFiles = sh.NameSpace(Shell32.ShellSpecialFolderConstants.ssfINTERNETCACHE);
            foreach ( Shell32.FolderItem item in tempFiles.Items() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's no `Delete` method on `Shell32.FolderItem` objects, but you should be able to use `InvokeVerb("delete")`.

Or, use `(Shell32.FolderItems2)tempFiles.Items()` and its `InvokeVerbEx` method to delete a whole bunch at once.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll give that a try and let you know.